# Sum and sort dollar amounts based on 2 variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a approx. 700 item data array with headers Month-Year, Total Dollar Amount, Location, and District. The rows all correspond to individual orders, each with a dollar amount, month-year, and location. I am looking for a way to sum the dollar amounts based on month-year and location.

Here you can see the original table with individual orders:

[image]

You can see there are two orders that have a sales office of Capitol and a month-year of Jan-15. There are three orders with the same sales office and a month-year of Feb-15. I would like to sum these corresponding values into a separate table, shown as an example below (Month and Year vs Total Sales Order Amount for each office):
[image]

Is there a relatively simple way to do this with excel? I can manually enter one by one but that would take quite a while.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula on Cell `C5`:

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$B:$B,Data!$A:$A,$B5,Data!$C:$C,C$3)
```

I don't have the position of your tables on the spreadsheet so I came up with the above formula, you have to take into account what each item of the formula is and replace accordingly if don't match in yours:

1. `Data!$B:$B`: Column where the dollars amounts are in the first image.
2. `Data!$A:$A`: Column where the dates are in the first image.
3. `Data!$C:$C`: Column where the locations are in the first image.
4. `$B5`: Cell where the date you are looking for is.
5. `C$3`: Cell where the locations you are looking for is.

Comment: I think this is going to work! I am playing around with it right now. Currently my trouble is that on the original sheet, the dates are formatted as month-year even though they are exact dates. On the new table, the dates are again formatted as month-year, but they are exact dates of the 1st of each month. Think I need to just convert these to text and it will work out.

Comment: Another option is to convert to the first day of the month

Comment: working on it. Regardless your solution will work. Just have to make edits to the dates. Thank you!!!

Comment: @piccolom5 please, accept the answer if it worked. Thanks!